# How to group windows in gnome overview

Tags: gnome

Is there a way to have windows grouped by application in the gnome shell "overview" (sorry, I don't know the correct term) that appears when pressing the super key?

Comment: The closest extension available related to windows in gnome overview is: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/18/native-window-placement/

Comment: hum, that doesn't have the feature I'm looking for

Comment: I'm going to add a bounty because I'd really like a way of having this. Hundreds of PDFs open makes it impossible to find anything else.

Comment: If you only need to switch tasks maybe you don't need overview. Have you tried ALT+TAB? It groups per application.

Comment: Well, yeah, there are other way (and I've functioned thus far with them). But that's not to say that I can't dream about having something better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a set of workarounds.

On my system, the overview opens quite slowly in a "usual" session (a dozen browser windows, other applications, ...) I use overview mainly for the search facility, task switching usually happens via <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>.

- The [Gno-Menu extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/608/gnomenu/) also has a search bar, the menu can be activated via <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- The [Window list extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/) displays the list of currently active tasks at the bottom. It can be configured to show only one button per application.
- The [Switcher extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/) (fairly new) allows selecting another application by typing its name after hitting <kbd>Super+W</kbd>.
- I used the Gnome Tweak tool to set the shortcut for switching between overview and desktop (in the "Keyboard and Mouse section") to <kbd>Super right</kbd> (which is not present on my keyboard). This is because hitting <kbd>Super left</kbd> if I want to open a new app is already in my muscle memory.

This essentially avoids the necessity to open the overview, ever.